# Merge files print 0 in empty field

Tags: awk

I have 5 tab delim files
file 0 is basically a key

```
A 
C 
F 
AA 
BC 
CC 
D 
KKK 
S
```

file1

```
A 2 
C 3 
F 5 
AA 5 
BC 4 
D 7
```

file2

```
A 2
C 3
F 7
D 10
```

file3

```
A 2
C 2
F 5
CC 4
D 7
```

file4

```
A 1
C 3
F 5
CC 4
D 7
KKK 10
```

I would like to merge all files based on the 1st column and print 0 in missing fields.

```
A 2 2 2 1
C 3 3 2 3
F 5 7 5 5
AA 5 0 0 0
BC 4 0 0 0
CC 0 0 4 4
D 7 10 7 7
KKK 0 0 0 10
S 0 0 0 0
```

Columns must keep the order of input file0, file1, file2, file3, file4

Comment: You're expected to include your own attempt to solve the problem in your question for us to be able to help you with it. See [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was going to wait til you included your own attempt in your question but since you have 2 answers already anyway....

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR==FNR {
    key2rowNr[$1] = ++numRows
    rowNr2key[numRows] = $1
    next
}
FNR==1 { ++numCols }
{
    rowNr = key2rowNr[$1]
    vals[rowNr,numCols] = $2
}
END {
    for (rowNr=1; rowNr<=numRows; rowNr++) {
        printf "%s", rowNr2key[rowNr]
        for (colNr=1; colNr<=numCols; colNr++) {
            printf "%s%d", OFS, vals[rowNr,colNr]
        }
        print ""
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file0 file1 file2 file3 file4
A 2 2 2 1
C 3 3 2 3
F 5 7 5 5
AA 5 0 0 0
BC 4 0 0 0
CC 0 0 4 4
D 7 10 7 7
KKK 0 0 0 10
S 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: It works perfect! My bad, I totally spaced out and forgot to post my failed attempts. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Not awk, but this sort of joining of files on a common field is exactly what [`join`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/join.1.html) is meant for. Complicated a bit by it only working with two files at a time; you have to pipe the results of each one into the next as the first file.

```
$ join -o 0,2.2 -e0 -a1 <(sort file0) <(sort file1) \
  | join -o 0,1.2,2.2 -e0 -a1 - <(sort file2) \
  | join -o 0,1.2,1.3,2.2 -e0 -a1 - <(sort file3) \
  | join -o 0,1.2,1.3,1.4,2.2 -e0 -a1 - <(sort file4) \
  | tr ' ' '\t'
A       2       2       2       1
AA      5       0       0       0
BC      4       0       0       0
C       3       3       2       3
CC      0       0       4       4
D       7       10      7       7
F       5       7       5       5
KKK     0       0       0       10
S       0       0       0       0
```

Caveats: This requires a shell like `bash` or `zsh` that understands `<(command)` redirection. Sorting all the files in advance is an alternative. Or as pointed out, even though `join` normally requires its input files to be sorted on the column that's being joined on, it works anyways without the sorts for this particular input.

Comment: In this special case you can keep the order of the lines if you replace all `<(sort fileX)` with `fileX`.

Comment: @Cyrus Huh.  I'm surprised that works; usually join will complain if the input isn't sorted on the join column. Interesting.

Comment: Interesting. I'm getting errors for some of the lines and the number of lines bigger than it should be. join: /dev/fd/62:11: is not sorted: AARS        862
join: /dev/fd/63:11: is not sorted: AARS        294
join: /dev/fd/63:10: is not sorted: AARS        452
join: /dev/fd/63:114: is not sorted: ADA        79

Comment: Unable to duplicate with your provided sample files.

Answer (score 2):

`awk` solution

```
awk '
    FNR==1{f++}
    {
        a[f""$1]=$2
        b[$1]++
    }
    END{
        for(i in b){
            printf i" "
            for(j=1;j<=f;j++){
                tmp=j""i
                if(tmp in a){
                    printf a[tmp]" "
                }else{
                    printf 0" "
                }
            }
            print ""
        }
    }
' file*
```

oupput :

```
A  2 2 2 1 
AA  5 0 0 0 
BC  4 0 0 0 
C  3 3 2 3 
CC  0 0 4 4 
D  7 10 7 7 
F  5 7 5 5 
KKK  0 0 0 10 
S  0 0 0 0
```

first i store every value for each file number and key value in variable a
then store all uniqe key in variable b

and in `END` block, checked if key is exists or not, if exists print it OR not exist print 0

we can delete `file0`, if delete it, `awk` show only exists key in file1,2,3,4,..

Comment: The `""`s in your script are doing nothing and you should never use printf with input data as the formatting string - imagine the difference between `printf $1` and `printf "%s", $1` when `$1` contains printf formatting chars like `%s`. The script will also add trailing blanks to every output line.

Comment: Almost works. Not sure why it outputs an extra 0s for some lines. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

With GNU awk you can use the `ENDFILE` clause to make sure you have enough elements in all rows, e.g.:

*parse.awk*

```
BEGIN { OFS = "\t" }

# Collect all information into the `h` hash
{ h[$1] = (ARGIND == 1 ? $1 : h[$1] OFS $2) }

# At the end of each file do the necessary padding
ENDFILE {
  for(k in h) {
    elems = split(h[k], a, OFS)
    if (elems !=  ARGIND)
      h[k] = h[k] OFS 0
  }
}

# Print the content of `h`
END {
  for(k in h)
    print h[k]
}
```

Run it like this:

```
awk -f parse.awk file[0-4]
```

Output:

```
AA  5   0   0   0
A   2   2   2   1
C   3   3   2   3
D   7   10  7   7
BC  4   0   0   0
CC  0   0   4   4
S   0   0   0   0
KKK 0   0   0   10
F   5   7   5   5
```

NB: This solution assumes you only have two columns per file (except the first one).

Comment: Almost worked. Just that there are some lines with empty 1st field... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could use coreutils `join` to determine missing fields and add them to each file:

```sh
sort file0 > file0.sorted
for file in file[1-4]; do 
  { 
    cat $file
    join -j 1 -v 1 file0.sorted <(sort $file) | sed 's/$/ 0/'
  } | sort > $file.sorted
done
```

Now you just need to `paste` them together:

```
paste file0.sorted \
  <(cut -d' ' -f2 file1.sorted) \
  <(cut -d' ' -f2 file2.sorted) \
  <(cut -d' ' -f2 file3.sorted) \
  <(cut -d' ' -f2 file4.sorted)
```

Output:

```
A   2   2   2   1
AA  5   0   0   0
BC  4   0   0   0
C   3   3   2   3
CC  0   0   4   4
D   7   10  7   7
F   5   7   5   5
KKK 0   0   0   10
S   0   0   0   0
```